# PHP: Number format using the function number_format

Tags: php

I have a very simple question regarding the number format.

I have this number 12456 and I would like to format as a price EUR 12 456

I found this script

```
number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ')
```

and the result is 12 456.00
How can I obatin 12 456 using the same function number_format()?

Comment: You should study Manual first, the second param is number of decimals.

Comment: Looking at `number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ')` the result can't be `12 456.00` but is `12 456,00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/number_format). Note: what you have found (`number_format`) is a *string function*, not a *script*.

Why not try to change the '2' to '0' like this?

`number_format($number, 0, ',', ' ')`

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `12 456` try: `number_format($number, 0, '', ' ');`